# SwiftUI Picker label

Tags: swiftui, picker

I have a code like this. like the code there is Image and label in content of picker. i want to when i tap on a picker option display only the label. but the problem is that both image and label will show up on the picker label. how should i fix this?

```
HStack {
    Picker(selection: $selectedVenueType) {
        ForEach(types, id:\.self) { type in
            HStack {
                Text(type)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                Spacer()
                if type != "Select venue type" {
                    Image(getImage(type: type))
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.04, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.04)
                }
            }
            .tag(type)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.78)
        }
    } label: {
        HStack {
            Text("selectedVenueType")
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                .labelStyle(.titleOnly)
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.78, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.05)
    }
    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.78, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height*0.05)
        .background(Color.white)
        .tint(Color.black)
        .cornerRadius(14) // Adjust the corner radius as needed
        .shadow(color: Color(red: 0.27, green: 0.27, blue: 0.27, opacity: 0.2), radius: 2, x: 0, y: 1)
}
```

This is the code of my picker.

Comment: if you don't want to show the Image, well just remove it. What is the problem here.

Comment: So you want the picker's label to not show an image, and only the options that appear in the menu should show an image? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the `Picker` in a `Menu`. You have much more control over the label of a menu, than the title of the picker's button.

Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selection: PickerOption = options[0]
    
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            Picker("Options", selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                    Label(option.title, systemImage: option.systemImage)
                }
            }
        } label: {
            // you can control a lot more things here
            // e.g. make it only show the selected item's title
            // and the "up-down" symbol
            HStack {
                Text(selection.title)
                Image(systemName: "chevron.up.chevron.down")
                    .imageScale(.small)
            }
        }

    }
}

struct PickerOption: Hashable {
    let title: String
    let systemImage: String
}


let options = [
    PickerOption(title: "Option 1", systemImage: "circle"),
    PickerOption(title: "Option 2", systemImage: "rectangle"),
]
```

Output:

[image] [image]

Side note: I would not recommend using the size of `UIScreen` to lay out your views.